# Adding Keepalive option to MySQL connection causes error "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

I am working on a project where a thread is run and opens a permanent database connection. The reason for this, is potentially as the project grows it could receive more and more requests so it's more efficient to keep the database open and usable instead of opening and closing the database.

Basically what the thread does is look for events in a queue, and if there is an event it starts working on the database to store and process the event. At its peak this thread could receive 50,000-100,000 requests a day potentially a lot more, as more and more users (hopefully) use the service.

However, because it's new, there are times where this thread doesn't have anything to do, so I end up hitting the exception "The connection must be valid and open" and I believe this is because the connection to the database is automatically dropped over 8 hours of inactivity. At the moment this can happen so I am trying to add a Keepalive option to the connection so this doesn't happen but for some reason, as soon as I add this, I then get the error "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts".

I am using a `MysqlConnectionStringBuilder` as follows:

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
connectionBuilder.Server = server;
connectionBuilder.UserID = username;
connectionBuilder.Password = password;
connectionBuilder.Port = 3306;

//Open the connection
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionBuilder.ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
```

This above works perfectly fine until I add the following:

```
connectionBuilder.Keepalive = 60;
```

When the above line is added is when I then get the error.

I am using a TCP connection as it's a remote connection from my Dev PC to a dev server - is there a setting on the server to enable this? as everything I've found on Google this option is all that's required.

Comment: Are you not using connection pooling? This is enabled by default in the MySQL Connector for .NET. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-pooling.html

Comment: I'm not no, just open a normal connection in the thread(s) that need it. Plan on taking a look at that at some point but just need a quick fix at the mo for the current issue :)

Comment: According to that documentation, connection pooling is enabled by default. In other words, if you didn't deliberately disable it, you're using connection pooling.

Comment: The KeepAlive option on the connection string isn't anything to do with connection pooling is it, its just a setting for that connection.

Comment: I understand that. I'm saying you may not need it. The connection pool achieves low-overhead connections when you request them.

Comment: I think maybe I have a misunderstanding of connection pools. I was thinking it was a completely different MySQL connector class but from a quick Google doesn't appear to be the case. I'm wondering if my problem isn't what I think as it looks like I should get Server has gone away for what I think is my problem but I'm getting connection must be valid and open so think maybe there's something else going on

Comment: I think it might be my DB connection is my own class, and I use that class which opens the database connection when its first instantiated and then enters a permanent while loop and re-uses that connection - I guess that affects how the connection pooling is working

Comment: Yes, I think you might have a misconception about how to use connection pools. The pool has a fixed number of connections (maximum 100 is the default). If your app opens 100 connections and does not return them to the pool, all 100 connections will be "in use" and the pool will return an error to the next thread that requests a connection. The proper way to use a pool is to `Close()` your connection when you're done with it, which returns the connection to the pool for the next request to use.

Comment: Yea I think I've fixed the issue potentially (need to test it as it hasn't been 8 hours) but I think I understand the concept now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction